# How Can I print correctly and compare $SESSION?

Tags: php, session, e-commerce, cart

I'm creating a shopping cart. Only with session variables. I want something simple, no database, it is only for initial system (later that perhaps use database and logins)

I click in a product and use URL to add in SESSION variable

Exemple
Product: Orange

Sent url

```
site.com/?page=buy&add=Orange&type=fruit
```

Then...

```
session_start();

//Create 'cart' if it doesn't already exist
if (!isset($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'])){ $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] = array(); }

if (isset($_GET['add'])){
//Adding an Item
//Store it in a Array
$ITEM = array(
    //Item name     
    'name' => $_GET['add'],
    'type' => $_GET['tipo'],

    //Item Price

    );
```

For print, I use:

```
 foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $item) {
 echo $item['type']; 
 echo $item['name'];
```

}

But My problem is, when I print I see something like this:
Fruit Orange
Fruit Apple
Fruir Banana

Someone can tell me how do I only appear once "Fruit". How do I comparison is already is repeated?

Example that I want:
Fruit
  Orange
  Apple
  Banana

Answer (score 0):

```
   $itemType = ""; 
   foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $item) {
     if($itemType == $item['type']) {
       // skip...don't print again
     } else { 
        echo $item['type']; 
     }
     echo $item['name']; 
     $itemType = $item['type'];
    }
```

Comment: it's possible to only print one name? Not repeat the name like fruit: banana, banana, banana

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add another level to the cart, e.g.

```
$_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$_GET['tipo']][$_GET['add']]
```

so you'd end up with a nested array structure:

```
 SHOPPING_CART -> fruit -> orange
               -> fruit -> apple
               -> vegetable -> pizza
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$itemType = ""; 
foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $item) {
 if($itemType == $item['type']) {
   // skip...don't print again
 } else { 
    echo $item['type']; 
 }
 echo $item['name']; 
 $itemType = $item['type'];
}
```

Great!

however if I have a problem. If I add a fruit, then a food, then a fruit:

```
Print:
   Fruit:
      Banana
      Banana
   Food:
      Meat x
   Fruit:
      Apple
```

However, it´s possible to not repeat the "banana" banana?

```
Print:
   Fruit:
      Banana
      Apple
   Food:
      Meat x
```